# One line "I want" questions

Tags: discussion

Recently I came upon a question that said "I want a abstract on...", with no other details. This strikes me as demanding and unreasonable. Should such questions be flagged as "rude or abusive", or am I being over-sensitive to this type of language?

Comment: I do not think that such questions are rude or abusive enough to merit flags (the red flags created when you hit "rude or abusive" are put into a high priority queue for moderation, and have extra impacts on users when/if the flag is marked as "helpful").  As @GerryMyerson suggests, a note suggesting that the author revise their language is a good idea.  Also a good idea:  vote to close the question (what you are describing is devoid of context, and *should* be closed).

Comment: @XanderHenderson I see, the post is deleted anyways so there is not much I can do. It is always nice to hear from a moderator though :)

Comment: You should only answer them if they [sing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22I_Want%22_song) their question. :-)

Comment: This definitely does sound unreasonable and demanding, but not "rude" or "offensive" to warrant such a rating.

Comment: Please keep in mind that not everyone is a native English speaker. I wouldn't consider that "rude or abusive", just a strange way of saying it. To me, "rude or abusive" means insulting statements such as "you're an idiot if you can't solve it on your own". Since "I want a ..." doesn't contain those kinds of statements, it's not rude or abusive.

Comment: @DavidLui - I definitely agree that it is neither rude nor abusive, and should not be flagged. But I also think that we are doing non-native English speakers a disservice if we don't make it clear that it is very abrupt, and, in a situation like math.se, where we are all doing favors for one another (i.e. no one here is a paid employee), it is too curt, and makes your question less likely to get a good reception.

Comment: I suppose _I would like_ is more polite in theory, but this isn't a German exam where one has to avoid conflating _Ich will_ with _Ich möchte_.

Comment: I've heard that English speakers around the world tend to expect more politeness markers than speakers of other languages. Not sure that's true, but it wouldn't be surprising.

Comment: "I want a solution to ..." seems actually a tiny bit more polite to me than the usual low-effort question we get, which is just a word-for-word copy of a homework problem, probably with a command like "Prove" somewhere in the middle.

Comment: I remember the days when Mariano would let users know they should not be using the imperative when asking questions. I always appreciated that, but unfortunately it seems that it was a losing battle.

Comment: I remember @Asaf's reply, with a link to a you-tube video-performance of The Rolling Stones song: "You can't always get what you want! (repeated, repeated), with the refrain ending with "But if you try sometime, you just might find, you get what you need!"

Comment: I agree, @CheerfulParsnip !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I wouldn't flag it as rude or abusive. I'd downvote it, and possibly explain why the question might be considered unreasonable.

My go-to response to one-liners that ask for volumes of work, is

> Try to spend as much effort writing the question, as you'd hope someone would spend writing an answer.

Because what I really don't like is a question that was written (or copy/pasted) in seconds, expecting a hundred times more effort from someone else.

Comment: Nontrivial problems—mathematical problems in particular—are generally easier to pose than to solve.

Comment: @JohnBentin - Agreed, but there are things an asker can do to play ball. Explaining what they've thought and done so far, linking to related posts that didn't pan out (showing that they did some research before asking), elaborating on dead-ends, etc. They don't need to put all the effort into the actual question, but rather outline effort spent researching, for example.

Answer (score 14):

So it seems that the general consensus of the community is that while the question is low-quality and demanding, it is not rude or abusive enough to qualify for a red flag.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes: please flag "rude and abusive" only if there is actual offensive content such as racism, homophobia etc. Spam and "not an answer" are also good options if appropriate.

Comment: @TobyMak Please do not flag these kinds of things as "spam".  Spam has a *very* narrow definition on the network, related to linking to off-site resources without declaring one's affiliations.

Answer (score 6):

My take is even more tolerant than that: My inclination is to cut people a lot of slack on stuff like this (especially considering that there are undoubtedly a *lot* of non-native English speakers on this site). This person may have taken a sentence that was entirely polite (not at all "demanding") in their own language and clumsily translated it word-for-word into English. It may be very brief for the same reason (limited English skills). If the meaning of a post is clear, and not overtly rude (like "your answer is stupid", etc.), I think it's totally fine and not the kind of thing SE should be "policing".

Comment: Translation or not, a one-liner with an instruction to solve a problem or provide a resource is not polite at all. I wouldn't accept being told to GTFO regardless of how many times you put *"please"* around it.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the Community to police poorly written Questions.  Translation problems can be addressed by offers of help and requests for clarification, but we want to close Questions that are overly broad or without context until these deficiencies are corrected.

Comment: There are different levels of policing, and it's pretty easy to leave a friendly comment noting that that's rather abrupt language to be using here. Especially if the rest of the question shows little effort.

Comment: Also, if you decide to comment on it, please try to suggest a better alternative phrasing. We want to help the poster communicate better, not merely nit-pick their English.

Comment: When you say "more tolerant than that", what is "that"?  Is it @bobeyt6's [answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35251)?

Comment: @Nij. It’s not an instruction to solve a problem, it’s just a statement of a desire. The question doesn’t tell us (or even ask us) to do something, it simply says that the OP wants something.

Comment: Oh boy, has contextual reading got a lesson for you! Walk into a cafe and say *"I want a large flat white"* to the people working there. See whether they do anything about it. @bubba

Comment: You really have to be careful about making culturally specific inferences about language. If I type 田中さんオフィスにおりません (Tanaka-san ofisu ni orimasen) into Google Translate, it will (correctly) translate this as "Mr. Tanaka is not in the office". How will it be perceived if I say such a sentence at work? It depends who I'm talking to and my relationship to Mr. Tanaka. It might be fine. But if I am talking to the CEO of my company and Mr. Tanaka is my manager, it's rude. I used the wrong word for "is" (and also I probably should have referred to Mr. Tanaka by his title, and not just "Mr.").

Comment: Foreigners unintentionally make these kinds of mistakes *all the time* in Japan. Would it be "fair" for a Japanese person to infer that I am an uncouth jerk for something like this? Nope. But here's the thing: they may have *no idea* that these distinctions (like different words for "is") don't exist in *my* native language.

Comment: Agreed. Such sentences can trivially be converted into questions (with the appropriate level of politeness). They may *lack* the English skills to pose questions (e.g., different word order and the required auxiliary verb). Or simply can't be bothered. We really don't know.

Comment: They might also just be unclear on what counts as "request" syntax in English. In Japanese, the standard polite way to say "may I have an X?" is Xおお願いします (X o onegai shimasu), but this is technically not in question syntax (literally, it's something like "I make a wish for X"). A rule like "reference requests should be in the form of a polite request" might seem straightforward, but non-native speakers may be legitimately confused about nuances like "will this grammatical form be interpreted as a 'demand' rather than a request?" and "is this considered polite 'tone' ***in English***?".

Comment: Off topic, but I think you mean X **を**お願いします.

Comment: Ah, yeah, correct. Typo on my part

Comment: "Off topic, but I think you mean ...". BTW, that's a perfect example of how to 'correct' someone's language in a comment.